# How to loop JSON data to get printed values of percentages for all objects using for each or other

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript-typings

How to iterate through an array of JSON data. Can you help with the code:

```
var percent=(100 * this.contributed) / this.max;
percent= Math.floor(percent);
```

This is the logic. I need to apply this for all objects using for each

```js
var dashboardval= [
    {"contributed": 20, "max": 35 },
    {"contributed": 22, "max": 35},
    {'contributed': 35, "max": 35,},
    {"contributed": 32, "max": 35}
   ];
```

Comment: I need percentage value for every object ..not single object

Answer (score 0):

Using ES6 you can do this by reducing the array of objects:

```js
var objects = [{"contributed": 20, "max": 35}, {"contributed": 22, "max": 35}, {'contributed': 35, "max": 35}, {"contributed": 32, "max": 35}];

var percent = objects.reduce((acc, {contributed, max}) => ~~((100 * contributed) / max));

console.log(percent);
```